# Simple EJB client or Junit not working with IBM websphere

Tags: exception, ejb, websphere, jndi

My ejb is deployed in websphere and i want to call it from another webserver, but the remote lookup code is not working. So i tried a simple client to see whether it works, i have set the context properties, but still its not working. Am i missing something?

My node location is WMSPBLDJ00327Node03Cell\WMSPBLDJ00327Node03\server1

The below jndi works perfectly from web code deployed in websphere.. ejb/WgePasEar/WgePasEjb.jar/EmplFacade#com.company.crw.wge.pas.ejb.cmn.empl.EmplFacadeHome
 but not from client. I tried different options as in the below code. Can you help?

EJB start up log

> [5/8/14 16:31:33:487 CDT] 0000004b AbstractEJBRu I   WSVR0037I: Starting EJB jar: WgePasEjb.jar
>   [5/8/14 16:31:34:101 CDT] 0000004b EJBContainerI I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.company.crw.wge.pas.ejb.cmn.empl.EmplFacadeHome interface of the EmplFacade enterprise bean in the WgePasEjb.jar module of the WgePasEar application.  The binding location is: ejb/WgePasEar/WgePasEjb.jar/EmplFacade#com.company.crw.wge.pas.ejb.cmn.empl.EmplFacadeHome
>   [5/8/14 16:31:34:105 CDT] 0000004b EJBContainerI I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.company.crw.wge.pas.ejb.cmn.empl.EmplFacadeHome interface of the EmplFacade enterprise bean in the WgePasEjb.jar module of the WgePasEar application.  The binding location is: com.company.crw.wge.pas.ejb.cmn.empl.EmplFacadeHome
>   [5/8/14 16:31:34:106 CDT] 0000004b AbstractEJBRu I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.company.crw.wge.pas.ejb.cmn.empl.EmplFacadeHome interface of the EmplFacade enterprise bean in the WgePasEjb.jar module of the WgePasEar application.  The binding location is: java:global/WgePasEar/WgePasEjb/EmplFacade!com.company.crw.wge.pas.ejb.cmn.empl.EmplFacadeHome

```
import java.util.Properties;import javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer;import javax.naming.Context;import org.junit.Test; public class TestJunit {

@Test
public void testContactBean() {
    // Create the embeddable container
    Properties env1 = new Properties();
    env1.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
    env1.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:9102");
    env1.put("com.ibm.CORBA.Debug", "true");
    env1.put("com.ibm.CORBA.CommTrace", "true");
    env1.put("com.ibm.CORBA.Debug.Output", "client.log");
    env1.put(
            "com.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL",
            "file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer_1/profiles/AppSrv1/properties/ssl.client.props");
    env1.put("com.ibm.CORBA.loginUserid", "admin");
    env1.put("com.ibm.CORBA.loginPassword", "admin");
    env1.put("com.ibm.CORBA.loginSource", "properties");
    EJBContainer ec = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(env1);

    try {
        Object ejbHome = null;
        try {
            ejbHome = ec
                    .getContext()
                    .lookup("java:global/WgePasEar/WgePasEjb.jar/EmplFacade#com.company.crw.wge.pas.ejb.cmn.scty.EmplFacadeHome");
            System.out.println("******************" + ejbHome);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            ejbHome = ec
                    .getContext()
                    .lookup("java:global/WgePasEar/WgePasEjb/EmplFacade!com.company.crw.wge.pas.ejb.cmn.empl.EmplFacadeHome");
            System.out.println("******************" + ejbHome);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Object contactBean = (Object) ec
                .getContext()
                .lookup("java:global/WgePasEar/WgePasEjb/EmplFacade!com.company.crw.wge.pas.ejb.cmn.empl.EmplFacadeHome");
        System.out.println("******************" + contactBean);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        ec.close();
    }
}}
```

All of these are giving me exceptions as name

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name WgePasEar not found in context "java:global".
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.getParentCtxInternal(NameSpace.java:1969)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.retrieveBinding(NameSpace.java:1376)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1219)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:1141)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookupExt(UrlContextImpl.java:1436)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookupExt(javaURLContextImpl.java:477)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookupExt(javaURLContextRoot.java:485)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookupExt(javaURLContextRoot.java:468)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:370)
>       at TestJunit.testContactBean(TestJunit.java:34)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name WgePasEar not found in context "java:global".
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.getParentCtxInternal(NameSpace.java:1969)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.retrieveBinding(NameSpace.java:1376)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1219)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:1141)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookupExt(UrlContextImpl.java:1436)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookupExt(javaURLContextImpl.java:477)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookupExt(javaURLContextRoot.java:485)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookupExt(javaURLContextRoot.java:468)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:370)
>       at TestJunit.testContactBean(TestJunit.java:42)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name WgePasEar not found in context "java:global".
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.getParentCtxInternal(NameSpace.java:1969)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.retrieveBinding(NameSpace.java:1376)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1219)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:1141)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookupExt(UrlContextImpl.java:1436)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookupExt(javaURLContextImpl.java:477)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookupExt(javaURLContextRoot.java:485)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookupExt(javaURLContextRoot.java:468)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:370)
>       at TestJunit.testContactBean(TestJunit.java:50)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Comment: I was looking at these two links and setting up the junit client.. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

[link](http://webspherepersistence.blogspot.com/2011/03/lightweight-jpa-testing-in-jee.html)
[link] (http://mresetar.blogspot.com/2012_06_01_archive.html)

Comment: Tried  this jndi name too                  cell/nodes/WMSPBLDJ00327Node03Cell/WMSPBLDJ00327Node03/server1/java:global/WgePasEar/WgePasEjb/EmplFacade!com.company.crw.wge.pas.ejb.cmn.empl.EmplFacadeHome

Answer (score 0):

The EJBContainer API should only be used from a standalone JVM, and it can only be used to access EJBs locally in that process (for unit-testing purposes for example), not remote EJBs in a server.  It's not exactly clear what the problem is in your Eclipse environment, but you might try setting the [trace system properties](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tejb_runemcontainer.html) (e.g., traceSpecification of `*=info`) in order to observe the `CNTR0167I` messages in the embeddable scenario.

For remote access, you should use the [EJB thinclient](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tcli_ejbthinclient.html) or the [application client container](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rcli_javacmd.html).  It is not possible to use `java:global` names with the EJB thinclient.

Comment: Hi bkail, thanks much for the reply... I tried with using trace and ejb thinclient... But not much info. Ho.. Please see the log.. http://pastebin.com/k96P4xQV

Comment: Any idea why its looking in serverlocal:CELLROOT/SERVERROOT instead of the actual node? WMSPBLDJ00327Node03Cell/WMSPBLDJ00327Node03/server1

Comment: Are you actually trying to use embeddable container or connect to a remote server?  To proceed on the embeddable problem, try `*=info` rather than `*=all`.  To proceed on the remote lookup problem, you need to remove the embeddable EJB container JAR from your classpath.

Comment: Thanks for helping... I removed the container, getting name not found exception.. Atleast now its looking into the same context i guess. I just need to access the ejb from a main program.. Logs are in this http://pastebin.com/AX77FjKi

Comment: I still don't know if you're actually trying to use embeddable container or connect to a remote server.  For embeddable container, you must use `java:global` names (and I don't know why your output doesn't show any modules starting). To connect to a remote server from a thinclient, you must use the `ejb/` names.

Comment: I got over that issue.. It worked after removing embeddable container.. Now when i am getting home object.. But when i try to create a remote i am getting an error saying stub class not found.. Now trying to create a stub... Will let you know the details.

Comment: I was trying to vote up, i guess i need more reputation.. :-(

Comment: now the client one is working , although it throws a null pointer in registry and i am able to connect, but not the one from webserver : Please check the above comment......i am using the same parameters...!! Removed all jars and used com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_8.5.0.jar alone.. http://pastebin.com/TWkhA5xf

Comment: Hi bkail, thanks much for helping me to get client working.. Do you have any clue with this error... http://www.pastebin.com/7y8J6swd... [13/05/2014 14:04:05:132 CDT] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.security.config.SecurityObjectLocator W Message Key:Could not obtain SecurityConfigObjectFactory on the client side. not found in resource bundle:com.ibm.ejs.resources.security 525 [P=844937:O=0:CT] ERROR com.company.cru.wge.pas.fltr.AuthFltr - Exception in AuthFltr - cru.wge.pas.cmn.excp.RrscLocrExcp: NamingException in RsrcLoctr.lkupEjbHm